# How to break from infinite loop, caused by PHP script running as root?

Tags: root, kill

I have PHP script running right now with root permissions that starts from the following lines:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', "log.txt");
```

It was accidentally started by web management panel from root user as cron task. Right now script is writing warnings caused by something like this `while(!feof($file_handle))` to file, increasing its size by 10 megabytes per second.

I don't have console root access to website, server owner is unavailable due to time difference. I only can run commands as root, once per minute, using cron from web panel (no output as you understand).

How can I stop my script from wasting system resources? Right now I delete file every minute with same cron script, so server can continue working. My linux knowledge is not enough to solve this problem without help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the command was executed as something like `php /path/to/script.php`, then you could do something like

```
pkill -f /path/to/script.php
```

or:

```
kill <pid>
```

where `<pid>` is the process id of the process running that you  want to kill.

You can also get the pid and executed line of the process with:

```
pgrep -fl /path/to/script.php
```

**NOTE**: the argument to `pkill` and `pgrep` should be something you **know is in the commandline**. The path is usefull if you called it that way, otherwise just use the name.

Comment: Probably best to use cron to get a process list, identify the pid, then kill it in a subsequent command.  To avoid the possibility of any trouble.

Comment: That is what I meant :D. I messed up the order.